# Unable to move from splash activity to main activity

Tags: android

Im using the following code to move from splash activity to MainActivity.

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(() -> {
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }, 1000);
```

Following is my activity declaration

```
<activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

        </activity>
```

The problem is that the splash activity is stuck and main activity is not being called. Why is that so?

Comment: What class contains the code you posted? Is it in a method? This context can help us better understand your question.

Comment: Put handler initialization inside onCreate();

Comment: Im having that handler in onCreate method

Comment: you can use countdowntimer to start main activity instead of handler

Comment: It seems correct. Use Debugger or logcat to confirm the application reaches the code inside the Handler.postDelayed()

Comment: And could you post your entire SplashActivity class